# How to block the thread javascript runs on?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rendering, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sleep in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript)

How can I block the execution for random amount of milliseconds to say do the `fadeIn` on several divs to pop them up on the screen one after the other, in sequential order, but appearing gracefully kinda like google top menu comes back little after the search box is rendered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sleep in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript) and about a million others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numDivs = 5;
var fadeDelay = 500;
for (i=1;i<=numDivs;i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {$("#div_"+i).fadeIn(fadeDelay)}, fadeDelay*i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function and a delay to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), but you can't force a thread to "sleep" in JavaScript.