# javascript slowly decrease volume of audio element

Tags: javascript, html

audio element is playing with volume:

```
audio.setVolume(.20)
```

At a certain point I want to fade out the volume, rather than have it cut abruptly, so in essence I want

```
audio.setVolume(.15)
audio.setVolume(.10)
audio.setVolume(.05)
audio.setVolume(.03)
audio.setVolume(.01)
```

but there needs to be some very brief delay in between these changes so they are audible and I get my fade out effect. What is the proper way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: You should look at [setTimeout() or setInterval()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript).

Answer (score 11):

You could use a [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval):

```
// Initial volume of 0.20
// Make sure it's a multiple of 0.05
var vol = 0.20;
var interval = 200; // 200ms interval

var fadeout = setInterval(
  function() {
    // Reduce volume by 0.05 as long as it is above 0
    // This works as long as you start with a multiple of 0.05!
    if (vol > 0) {
      vol -= 0.05;
      audio.setVolume(vol);
    }
    else {
      // Stop the setInterval when 0 is reached
      clearInterval(fadeout);
    }
  }, interval);
```

Comment: You don't need to set a multiple of 0.05 if you test ` if (vol >= 0.0.5)`. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Titou Doing some archaeology? Yes you're correct I think. Any starting volume would work if the condition is `>= 0.05` and the subtractor is exactly 0.05 so it reaches zero. Would there be additional floating point weirdness? I don't know. There might already have been.

Answer (score 7):

I would wrap the `setTimeout` inside of the function, as well as the options. Regarding the factor, `0.01` will be a safe value to decrease without you having to know or adjust the initial value.

```
function fadeVolume(volume, callback)
{
    var factor  = 0.01,
        speed   = 50;
    if (volume > factor)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            fadeVolume((audio.volume -= factor), callback);         
        }, speed);
    } else {
        (typeof(callback) !== 'function') || callback();
    }
}
fadeVolume(audio.volume, function(){
    console.log('fade complete');
});
```

Once the fade is complete, it will fire a callback that you can use to  play the next song.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this mouse key event too.

```
audio.on('keydown', function() {
// and here keep increasing or decreasing the volume, untill keyUp
})
```

As being viewed, its jQuery! You can use it for your work. Also, the audio tag is for the div, that contains the audio tag!