# sleep in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sleep in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript)

I want to make a **sleep** function in JavaScript, I have to stop any code execution before the user performs an action (like the alert() behaviour)

What I need is exactly: what should I insert here to make it work?

```
window.alert = function(message){
    var dialog = $('<div>'+message+'</div>').dialog({
        title:'Alert',

        buttons:{
            'Ok': function(){
                $(this).dialog('close').data('open', false);
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    }).data('open', true);
    //What to insert here?
}
```

Comment: This questions has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript

Comment: no, I am overriding the standard alert, so I cannot pass a function as parameter, I want to execute the code AFTER the alert, not something in parameter

Comment: If you pretend my question is answered there, then what should I insert in my code to make it work???

Comment: @kooliilies you can't just sleep. You're whole code will need to be changed.

Comment: You just can't, you need to user either callbacks, either with the deferreds of Daniel A. White or with my solution.

Comment: @kooliilies, I apologize, I was referring emulating a sleep function in JS, which that post *does* answer, but I think Daniel A. White, and  Tronix117 have given you a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/?s=deferred) are the best way to do this. It provides a nice callback framework so that its easier to maintain callbacks.

I have made a new function because some browsers may not let you redefine `alert`.

```
myAlert = function(message){
var dfd = new $.Deferred();

var dialog = $('<div>'+message+'</div>').dialog({
    title:'Alert',

    buttons:{
        'Ok': function(){
            $(this).dialog('close').data('open', false);
            $(this).remove();
            dfd.resolve();
        }
    }
}).data('open', true);
return dfd.promise();
}
```

Then

```
myAlert(message).done(function() { callback here });
```

if you want what you commented on, it would be this way.

```
myAlert(1).done(function() { myAlert(2) });
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `setTimeout()` implementation be better? BTW - I didn't downvote you!

Comment: no, because that works on a predetermined amount of time. Deferreds work with async operations.

Comment: I cannot use Jquery deferreds, how to achieve this?
alert(1);
alert(2);

alert(2) should execute after alert(1) is dismissed

Comment: why can't you? what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I have to use **alert** because the code is full of alerts, and othe programmers are willing to add other alerts too...

Comment: thats fine. but i change it to `myAlert` because some web browsers may not allow you to redefine `alert`.

Comment: **alert** I mean take **one** parameter, not **tow** in your example, you have to know which code to be executed after the alert, but I don't know..

Comment: @kooliilies because JavaScript is interactive you can't stop the code execution. So there's no sleep function. The given answers show everything what's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a callback here, because if you deactivate the javascript, the user will not be able to click on 'OK'

```
window.alert = function(message, callback){
    var dialog = $('<div>'+message+'</div>').dialog({
        title:'Alert',

        buttons:{
            'Ok': function(){
                $(this).dialog('close').data('open', false);
                $(this).remove();
                typeof callback=='function' && callback(); //check if callback, and execute it
            }
        }
    }).data('open', true);
}
alert('test',function(){console.log('The user has clicked on the ok');});
```

**EDIT:**

If you only want to pause `alert` execution and not the other code execution you can do something like this (I haven't tried it, but the idea is here):

```
var alertStack=[];
window.alert = function(message){
  if(!message || !alertStack.length)
    $('<div>'+(alertStack[0] || message)+'</div>').dialog({
      title:'Alert',

      buttons:{
        'Ok': function(){
          alertStack.shift()
          $(this).dialog('close').data('open', false);
          $(this).remove();
          alertStack.length && alert();
        }
      }
    }).data('open', true);

  message && alertStack.push(message);
}
alert('test');
alert('test2');
alert('test3');
```

Comment: I know how to use callbacks!! I wrote several jQuery plugins... what I want is to use the standard alert (the code uses thousands of alert calls, would take years to fix it...)

Comment: @kooliilies you can stop JavaScript with `while(true){}` but this will kill the browser and will make it impossible to click on one of the buttons. You should use something like this there's no other solution!!!

Comment: I uploaded the script to only pause successions of alert, it means `alert(1);alert(2);` will work, but not `alert(1);a=2;alert(2);`, if the first dialog is printed, `a` will already be `2`

Comment: Thank you for your effort, actually what I want is that my new alert behaves **EXACTLY** like the original window alert

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout() when you want to defer the execution of code but do not want it to be repeatedly executed.