# Javascript sleep function feasable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sleep in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript)
>   [What do I do if I want a JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Is it possible to implement a sleep function in Javascript?

I have this code:

```
var state = true;
$('#changeState').click(function(){
  if (state == true)
    state = false
  else
    state = true
})
while() {
  //do something
  if (state == false){
    sleep();
  }
}
```

Is it feasable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to execute a certain action if the state becomes true, why not just start this action after you set state to true? There is no need for a sleep() method in Javascript like that ... you should describe better what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: on an unrelated side-note you can just use `$('#changeState').click(function(){state = !state;});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you attempt to make the browser "busy wait" it will become unresponsive, and may generate warnings to that effect.

You **must** allow the normal event processing loop to continue, or your `click` handler will never be called.