# Pause javascript execution while waiting on response

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to pause a javascript function while waiting for the user to make a choice. I would like it to work like prompt, alert or confirm (they pause the script) but I would like to create my own query box in html.

Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous

Comment: @MikeChristensen What do you mean by that?

Comment: @user916276 - See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) - Notably: *When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.*

Comment: Related: [Sleep in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/758688/2460971)

Answer (score 2):

Setup a callback that will be called when the user make the choice then let the javascript end after showing the choices to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know any good tutorial that shows how to write a good callback function?

Comment: this is an example http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events taken from here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp which is a nice site

Comment: But does a callback really pause the execution of the javascript code?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Nothing pauses a JavaScript thread - there's no sleep function.  What the callback does is that it waits for a specific action to finish before commencing executing on the code within the callback

Comment: the javascript thread pauses when ends. but the javascript engine keeps running if there are callback that may be triggered by events.

Comment: I will look closer into callbacks. Thanks!

Comment: if this seem to you the be right answer (but only in that case!) you may also consider the option to flag it as the right answer. This is how things are supposed to go on Stack O.