# delay function in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sleep in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript)

i am writing div dynamically using javascript.

i need a delay time for writing one div to another div.

am using for loop to write a div dynamically.

sleep function not working..

my code like,

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   sleep(100);
   $("#"+i).html("hi"+i);
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i think instead of `break` you should use `continue`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `setTimeout()`.

Do a google search and you'll see lots of example usages.

Comment: where can i use setTimeout()..?

Comment: first I suggest you find out how it works... and then figure out how to implement into your code. If you understand it yourself it's much better than someone simply giving you the code.

Comment: [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the getTimeout function, which takes a callback and a number of milliseconds to wait before calling it.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    setTimeout((function(i) {
        return function() {
            $("#"+i).html("hi"+i);
        };
    })(i), 100) 
}
```

Comment: 1) Typo: it's `setTimeout`. 2) Classic bug: this will fire `$("#10").html("hi10");` 10 times, since `i` changes before the function is called.

Comment: Yes, you're right. See edit.

Comment: Good work with the quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval(function, miliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

As previously suggested, use setTimeout(). You have details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: [w3schools sucks](http://w3fools.com/#why-w3schools-sucks)

Comment: An alternative that does not suck?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use `setTimeout`, using it in a inner function:

```
function writeDivs() {
  var i = 0;
  var divsToCreate = 100;
  var timeToSleep = 100;
  var createOneDiv = function () {
    if (i < divsToCreate) {
      $("#"+i).html("hi"+i);
      i++;
      setTimeout(createOneDiv, timeToSleep);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(createOneDiv, timeToSleep);
}
```