# JavaScript: wait 0.01 milliseconds

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make JavaScript to wait for 0.01 milliseconds? I'd like to place it inside a for loop, such that the time interval between each iteration is 0.01 milliseconds.

Comment: There's `setTimeout()`. You can't make a JavaScript thread "wait" however.

Comment: 0.01 millisecond ? Do you realize how quick that is... I believe the you can't have a time unit smaller that 1 millisecond.

Comment: The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers) also specifies a minimum interval of 4ms.

Comment: If you intend to run JavaScript with 10 μsec resolution you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: Don't you mean 0.01 seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sleep in Javascript - delay between actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript-delay-between-actions)

Answer (score 4):

You can't make JS "wait". You can only defer operations to a later time, and the engine continues to execute, only pulling in deferred operations when the engine is doing nothing.

The closest JS would have to a "waiting loop" is `setInterval(fn, 0)`. But it's never really zero delay. Most engines cap it at 4ms. Plus, delays are "minimums", not guarantees. They're not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create an interval timer, and only have that run so many times:

```
functionToRun(){
  if (counter<1000) {
    //keep running, and do stuff
  }
  counter++
}

var counter=0;
var functionToRun = setInterval("functionToRun();",100);
//100 is milliseconds
```

This will start your function right away.  But it will only fire 1000 times.  That's the basic idea.  You can play with it to do what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function

```
setInterval(function(){...},0.01);
```

But you can't really pause the thread.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(yourfunctionhere,0.01);

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Pufflegamerz_Studios/g9Lwfh2r/

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hello!")
}, 0.001)
```