# Delay time between each clicks on class

Tags: javascript

I have some loop like below..which clicks all buttons

```
for(var i = 1;i<document.querySelectorAll(".myclass").length;i++){

document.querySelectorAll(".myclass")[i].click();
console.log("hi");

};
```

but I want to add sleep function that delays each loop like sleep(2000); , Is there any function in javascript like that ?

I tried below code , but does not work

```
for(var i = 1;i<document.querySelectorAll(".myclass").length;i++){


setTimeout(function() {

document.querySelectorAll(".myclass")[i].click();
console.log("hi");

}, (3 * 1000));




};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sleep in Javascript - delay between actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript-delay-between-actions)

Comment: you cant directly set a timeout for the iteration itself, but you can call a timeout within each iteration

Comment: stop down voting..I just placed setinterval inside , but it doesnt run the loop

Comment: The `setTimeout` executes the click 3 seconds later, but since the loop continues without stopping, it will click ALL links 3 seconds later, all at once.

Comment: yea I so what will be the correct way to delay clicks between each loops??

Comment: Note that Javascript works asynchronously, so there is not really a sleep method. You should take a look at callbacks. That way, you can synchronize the clicks.

Comment: An other way is to use an `setInterval()`, and use a custom counter.

Comment: can you tell me correct steps ? so I must use setInterval inside function and call another function outside>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 2000);
var divIndex = 0;
function myTimer() {
    if(divIndex < document.querySelectorAll(".myclass").length){
      document.querySelectorAll(".myclass")[divIndex].click();  
       console.log(divIndex); 
    }else {
     clearInterval(myVar);
    }
    divIndex++;
}
```

```html
<div class='myclass'></div>
<div class='myclass'></div>
<div class='myclass'></div>
<div class='myclass'></div>
```

Comment: Please try with this. it will not crash your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Create the new function as give and call that function inside your loop.

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while ((new Date().getTime() - start) < milliseconds) {

    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks ! but your script is crashing my browser..any idea ?

Comment: What is the length of the querySelectorAll(".myclass") ?

Comment: I have try with 25 its working fine please add loop code in onload function

Comment: Let me find another solution for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96014/discussion-between-mitul-and-vishnu).