# How to make this script active after 1 second?

Tags: javascript, timeout

Edit: Not a timeout, it should be like active after 2 seconds. Else it disturbs the scroll on focus script.

I have this script here, but would like to have a timeout for 1 or 2 seconds.

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

There should not be an instant blur, else my 'scroll on focus input' will not work. Can anyone help? Thanks already.

```
$("#myInput").click(function () {
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#osb").offset().top }, 300);
return true;
```

});

```html
      <div id="osb">
 <div id="osb01">
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search.." title="Search">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sleep in JavaScript - delay between actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript-delay-between-actions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTimeout`

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    setTimeout( function(){ document.activeElement.blur() }, 1000 ); //1000 milliseconds
});
```

**Edit**

Since you don't want to defocus the search bar, then check if the current active element is not search bar

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if ( document.activeElement.id == "myInput" ) //assuming that search bar id is myInput
    {
        setTimeout( function(){ document.activeElement.blur() }, 1000 ); //1000 milliseconds
    }
});
```

## myInput

Comment: I just noticed, I did not explained it well enough. I meant, the script should be starting to work after 1 or 2 seconds. Because now its removing focus after 1 second, which is bad I see. Thank you already but could you help me with this, too?

Comment: @Albeld Which script should start working after 1 or 2 seconds? You mean that unless user the scroll stays for 1 or 2 seconds, blur shouldn't happen?

Comment: I mean right now if I focus the search bar, it scrolls down untill you only see the search bar on top. With this script it focuses out again due the scrolling. So if the script would work after a few seconds, it could scroll down to the search bar and stay focused.

Comment: I add the script I have for scrolling on focus

Comment: @Albeld ohh, there was fair amount of info missing from your original question... I think you should exclude search bar from the check. If `document.activeElement` is not search bar, only then blur should be triggered.

Comment: sorry I'm new here and need to get into it.

Comment: it is still losing focus after scroll (scroll on focus script)

Comment: @Albeld Check if you were using the correct id for search bar

Answer (score 0):

gurvinder32 right, but there is better way to do this.

```js
document.onscroll = function() {
  var active = document.activeElement;
  setTimeout(function() {
    active.blur();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: black;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input value="test1">
<input value="test2">
<input value="test3">
<input value="test4">
<input value="test5">
<input value="test6">
<input value="test7">
<input value="test8">
<input value="test9">
<input value="test10">
```

This method remembers active element before timeout, so if user change focus before timeout, then old element `blurs`, so nothing changes.

Comment: thanks but its losing focus after it scrolls down. now its like this: focus input > scrolls down > focus lost. i need to keep focused but on scrolling again it should focus out.