# Is there anyway to make the entire js script delay?

Tags: javascript

I tried to use async and await but it didn't work because it runs in the background. I would like a way to make the entire script kinda sleep, like time.sleep in Python.

I tried using async and await with code looking like this:

```
const sleep = (delayInms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayInms));
};

async function Delay() {
    console.log("0s");
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log("1s");
}

function main() {
    Delay();
    console.log("1s also")
}
```

I am working with HTML, CSS and JS. This resulted returning
`1s also`
in the console at the same time as
`0s`

Comment: No.  Use `setTimeout` -- that's what it is for.

Comment: I use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` for this sort of thing. How you'd use them in your context depends on what you're doing and how your code is structured.

Comment: `async function main() {
    await Delay(); ...` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: also [Sleep in JavaScript - delay between actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758688/sleep-in-javascript-delay-between-actions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are not waiting for the `Delay` function to complete its execution.

When `main()` is called, it invokes `Delay()` but does not **wait** for it to complete as it was not instructed to. Instead, it immediately moves to the next line and executes console.log("1s also").

While waiting for the *1000ms* to pass, the main thread continues executing `console.log("1s also")`.

JavaScript in the browser operates on a [*single-threaded event loop*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop) model. When a `setTimeout()` function is executed, the callback is added to the browser's ***task queue*** after the specified delay. It waits in the queue until the main thread is free to execute it. In the meantime, the rest of the code is executed.

To prevent this, you can either make your `main` function asynchronous and `await` for the Delay:

```js
async function main() {
    await Delay()
    console.log("1s also")
}
```

Or, you can use the old classic way of `.then` method:

```js
function main() {
    Delay().then(() => {
      console.log("1s also")
    })
}
```